# Got a problem whit next.js and nextauth,i think the problem is simple but im so out of practice

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am creating my first e-commerce website, until now I was only studying the front end but I wanted to start learning the back end. I am using Next. js, tailwinds and NextAuth.js to make my admin panel but I am getting the following error:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG6EI.png)

My code is quite simple, and I'm following a youtube tutorial, but given the differences in versions of the libraries I'm using I'm afraid I've messed up, here is the code of the index and layout, I would be very grateful to hear your recommendations, I was frustrated by the job competition for a long time and I'm just returning to develop and I'm feeling a little overwhelmed. here is the code:
[page.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpju4.png)

[layout.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QL1C.png)

Many thanks in advance

I have even tried to start the project from 0, but I keep getting the same error